# Software Testing Library to connect and test external system

Tags: python, automation, software-testing

I'm looking for library recommendations in python (or other languages) that can help me connect to a remote system and then deploy applications asynchronously and then test the output of the stdouts of each application against expected sets of conditions. The software would ideally:

- support serial connection (input/output)
- support SSH connection (input/output)
- allow hooks to test the output with string searches and regular expressions
- boilerplate test/summarize/cleanup built into the framework

I did a little bit of this with ansible but I noticed that I was spending too much time working around their original use case which is configuration management but I liked the flexibility that it did provide. Another one was Google's OpenHFT but that one is lacking plugs (their nomenclature for connection types, e.g., SSH, serial) so it would be similar to writing my own tool. Wondering if there are other frameworks already out there that is dedicated to testing external systems. I'm hoping to avoid starting from scratch.

Comment: Do you really need to deeply remotely? Could you not run on localhost and map the "remote" ip address/port to localhost in your hosts file?

Comment: I never heard such a thing. An IP connection is an IP connection and thus requires an IP protocol in order to send/receive data so which linux tool hides the IP connection to a testing suite/test runner?

Comment: Sorry, I think that we are both misunderstanding each other. I was suggesting that instead of testing on xyz.com, you run the code on localhost and edit /etc/hosts (? I think that's it), to route xyz.com to localhost

Comment: There isn't a web server running on the system so I think your suggestion is for something not valid to my specification. Please note that the protocol specification is `support SSH and serial`. Although, I wouldn't mind including others too like HTTP, etc. Are we understanding each other now?

Comment: Yes, getting closer :-)  Sorry, I thought it was just HTTP(S)